# Tuleap error 500 REST API

Tags: api, tuleap

I installed tuleap 7.7 on a Centos VM.

Web access works.

When I try to use the REST API, I have the following error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error: addAPIClass('\\Tuleap\\Project\\REST\\ProjectResource') failed. Class Tuleap\\AgileDashboard\\REST\\v1\\OrderRepresentation does not exist"
  },
  "debug": {
    "source": "Routes.php:85 at setup stage",
    "stages": {
      "success": [

      ],
      "failure": [
        "message"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas about what exactly? You have an internal server error. What have you tried so far to resolve it?

Comment: I only installed tuelap with the procedure:http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html api rest should work but apparently something missing: Class Tuleap \\ \\ AgileDashboard REST v1 \\ \\ OrderRepresentation does not exist how to install this class?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install and enable the AgileDashboard plugin in the Administration of Tuleap.